# Clean Architecture with MediatR, how does one handle SelectListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, clean-architecture

**Background:**

I am building an "admin application" ([GitHub](https://github.com/jwankhalaf/bejebeje.admin/tree/feat/ability-to-add-new-artist)) to manage another community-driven lyrics web application. Users that sign up can submit new artists and lyrics and the admin application I'm building will allow an admin or a moderator to approve new submissions ...etc.

I built the admin application based on [Jason's Clean Architecture solution template](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture). The template uses a SPA built in Angular as the front-end and I wanted regular MVC with Razor views, so I had to get rid of the Client app and change my controllers so that they would return Views instead of JSON.

All went well.

**Problem:**

I now want to create the ability to add a new artist, so I have an initial `GET` request action to load the form, and a `POST` request action to handle the submission.

On the `GET` request, the view model that I need to return has a `SelectListItem` to create a drop down (for gender selection) on the Razor view.

**ArtistsController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
{
    CreateArtistGenderDto viewModel = await Mediator.Send(new CreateArtistQuery());
    
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Create(CreateArtistCommand command)
{
    return await Mediator.Send(command);
}
```

**CreateArtistQuery.cs**

```
public class CreateArtistQuery : IRequest<CreateArtistGenderDto>
{
}

public class CreateArtistQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateArtistQuery, CreateArtistGenderDto>
{
    public async Task<CreateArtistGenderDto> Handle(
        CreateArtistQuery request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        CreateArtistGenderDto model = new CreateArtistGenderDto();

        return model;
    }
}
```

**CreateArtistGenderDto.cs**

```
namespace bejebeje.admin.Application.Artists.Queries.CreateArtist;

public class CreateArtistGenderDto
{
    public Gender SelectedGender { get; set; }
    
    public List<SelectListItem> GenderOptions = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))
    };
}

public enum Gender
{
    Female,
    Male,
    NotApplicable
}
```

The issue is, if I follow the MediatR pattern and place my `Query` class in the **Application** project, that project does not know what a `SelectListItem` is and if I add a reference to the package, I'll be breaking the nice dependency chain that I currently have.

[image: clean architecture]

In other words, the dependencies will no longer flow inward, but they'll go outward too and we've been told that is "bad" and creates a mess.

[image: selectlistitem issue]

What is the right way of going about this without breaking the dependency chain/flow?

Comment: Move the creation of the `SelectListItem` list to the action. `SelectListItem` is a UI/Presentation concern handled by the controller.

Comment: My understanding was that things coming back from the MediatR call would be ready to be passed on to the View without further processing. Are you saying that's the wrong mental model to have?

Comment: Not saying it is wrong mental model, just that it does not work for this scenario

Comment: Provide the options as values and build the `SelectListItem` closer to the UI so that it remain in the correct domain

Comment: I would use the `ViewBag` to hold on to things like that

Comment: How would this look in practical terms? Would I create a `ViewModels` folder in the **WebUI** project and create a ViewModel within that directory that makes use of the `Gender` enum and build the `SelectListItem` in there?